# How can I make a clustered heatmap from an unclustered matrix?

Tags: cluster-analysis

I have a similarity matrix and when I plot it as a heatmap, it looks like:

[image]

I have tried using 'Agglomerate' to cluster the underlying matrix but I cannot figure out how to get the clusters to show in a new heatmap.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the package ["HeatmapPlot.m"](https://github.com/antononcube/MathematicaForPrediction/blob/master/Misc/HeatmapPlot.m). Below are given examples.

```mathematica
Import["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/antononcube/MathematicaForPrediction/master/Misc/HeatmapPlot.m"]
```

Make a random symmetric matrix:

```mathematica
SeedRandom[23];
{m, n} = {80, 50};
mat = RandomReal[{0, 100}, {m, n}];
mat = SparseArray[RandomSample[Most@ArrayRules@SparseArray[mat], Floor[4*m]]];
mat = mat.Transpose[mat];
MatrixPlot[mat, MaxPlotPoints -> 300]
```

[image]

Heatmap plot with clustering for the random symmetric matrix:

```mathematica
HeatmapPlot[mat, Dendrogram -> True, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

You can specify distance function and linkage:

```mathematica
Grid[Table[
  HeatmapPlot[ mat, 
   Dendrogram -> True, 
   DistanceFunction -> dist,
   HierarchicalClustering`Linkage -> link, 
   PlotLabel -> {dist, link}, ImageSize -> Medium],
  {dist, {EuclideanDistance, CosineDistance}},
  {link, {"Single", "Complete", "Ward"}}], 
  Dividers -> All, FrameStyle -> GrayLevel[0.8]]
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe I don't understand something fundamentally, but the matrix is symmetric along one diagonal, but the dendrograms seem to set the symmetry along the other diagonal. Please, explain.

Comment: The dendrograms are derived by the column- and row-similarities. They might "imply" order that is not immediately obvious from the matrix plot. Also, if the matrix plots are made with larger number of points the impressions they give might be different.

Comment: Yes, ok.. Still. Take a look here https://www.researchgate.net/publication/51822002_Multivariate_modeling_to_identify_patterns_in_clinical_data_The_example_of_chest_pain/figures?lo=1 It seems that dendrogram at the right should be flipped along horizontal axis.

Comment: @ФилиппЦветков Thanks, I will read the article later this week...